.NET NamedPipes client/server troubles. Server can't reply back to client - "Cannot access closed pipe"
I'm trying to create a basic client/server message exchange between two .NET applications. I want the client to connect to the server and then send a message. The server will then receive this message, and reply back with a result.  I'm intending to implement a basic API.
Server code looks like this:
// PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity() and ACL rules here...

NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = NamedPipeServerStreamAcl.Create("my_pipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 10, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, default, default, ps);

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);

while (true)
{
    try 
    {
        // Wait for a connection
        pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

        // Read the message from the client
        string messageFromClient = sr.ReadLine();
        Trace.WriteLine($"IPC Message Reveived: {messageFromClient}", "info");

        // Reply back to the client
        sw.WriteLine("PONG!");
        sw.Flush();

        pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();

        pipeServer.Close();


    } catch (Exception ex) {

        Trace.WriteLine($"ipc_server error: {ex}", "error");

    } finally {

        pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();

        if (pipeServer.IsConnected) { 

            pipeServer.Disconnect(); 

        }
    }

and then on the client, i have the following;
var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".",
  "my_pipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None);

try
{
    // Connect to pipe
    if (pipeClient.IsConnected != true) { pipeClient.Connect(); }

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);

    // Send a message
    sw.WriteLine("PING!");
    sw.Flush();

    pipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();

    // Perhaps my client is closing or not waiting long enough here
    // for the server to reply??

    // Receive a message
    string message_from_server = sr.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(message_from_server);

    pipeClient.Close();

} catch (Exception ex) {

    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}");
}

Im then getting the following error on the server. No errors are thrown on the client and the client does not see the pong.:
info: IPC Message Reveived: PING!
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.IO.Pipes.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.IO.Pipes.dll
Cannot access a closed pipe.

Im thinking its something to do with the client closing the pipe before the server replies, but im struggling to work out if thats the issue and how to resolve it.
Any help welcome!  Would also welcome feedback on my error handling and how to get the server non-blocking as well, thats my next job.

do you get PONG on the client?

@Ivan Petrov- no PONG on the client.

There are multiple issues that I recognize just at first glance:

You are in a while(true) loop in the server and you Close the Pipe at the end of the first iteration. Then at the next iteration you will call pipeServer.WaitForConnection(); guaranteed to get ObjectDisposedException.

Even in the first iteration you will get that because you execute methods on a closed pipe in the finally block of the server.
 ...
 pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();

 pipeServer.Close(); // this closes -> initiates Disposing

 } finally {
 // pipeServer is Closed here...aka Disposed/Disposing 
 pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain(); // probably throws here

 if (pipeServer.IsConnected) { 

     pipeServer.Disconnect(); 

 } 



For an okay intro-example to achieve what you want, I've modified your initial example with this functionality.

The server echoes back what the client sent in upper case.
The client reads user input from the console and sends the input to the server and outputs the server's response. If you write "EXIT" the client exits.

At this point you can connect another client etc. When you are done with server Ctrl+C in the server console window. Not bullet-proof or anything but good enough to experiment more.
Server (example Security...use whatever works for you)
static void Main(string[] args) {
    PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();
    var id = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);
    ps.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(id, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

    NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = NamedPipeServerStreamAcl
    .Create("my_pipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 10,
    PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, default, default, ps);


    Console.CancelKeyPress += (o, e) => pipeServer.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Named Pipe Server started. Press Ctrl+C to exit");
    while (true) { // this is for the next client
        try {
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);

            sw.WriteLine("Hello. Will ECHO until you write EXIT");
            sw.Flush();
            pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();


            while (true) { // message loop with this client

                string messageFromClient = sr.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(messageFromClient);

                if (messageFromClient == "EXIT") {
                    break;
                }

                var replyMessage = "Server ECHO: " + messageFromClient.ToUpper();
                sw.WriteLine(replyMessage);
                sw.Flush();
                pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();

            }

            if (pipeServer.IsConnected) {
                pipeServer.Disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}

Client
static void Main(string[] args) {
    using var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".",
          "my_pipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None);
    try {
        pipeClient.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to server");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);

    string introMessageServer = sr.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(introMessageServer);

    while (true) { // client loop 
        try {
            var message = Console.ReadLine();
            sw.WriteLine(message);
            sw.Flush();
            pipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();

            if (message == "EXIT") {
                break;
            }

            string message_from_server = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(message_from_server);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}


if I comment out the pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain() line, i get the following error : Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.IO.Pipes.dll
error: ipc_server error: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed pipe.
at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.CheckConnectOperationsServer()
at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnection()
at myapp.ipc_server.start() in C:xxx\ipc_server.cs:line 34

@Toby every WaitForPipeDrain call that happens after Close will do that (even in the next iteration of the loop)

@Toby just for the time being remove all Close() calls for diagnostic purposes in the server

Thankyou for helping Ivan. I have removed the close() statements and the finally block. I'm getting a PONG back from the server now. But the server gets upset still - Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
error: ipc_server error: System.InvalidOperationException: Already in a connected state.

@Toby I've modified my answer to give you testing code that doesn't face the same issues yours does with better life-time management of server/client (still not production-ready or anyting) but we are getting out of the scope of the original question anyway.

A better resource management would be encapsulating all the pipeClient inside a using statement, so a proper resource disposal is done if exceptions are raised. eg using (var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(....)) { /* all the pipeClient code */ }

@Cleptus it is already like this ? just the new syntax of using:
 using var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".",           "my_pipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None);

yeah, you are right, my bad. When no code blocks are used then the using would dispose at the end of the scope. In your code that would be at the end of the main

@Cleptus yeah, kind of pointless I know. But we are the top level scope anyway aren't we? If you have editing powers please suggest and edit and I'll accept it.

@ivanPetrov amazing, thank you so much. When I'm back home I will give it a whirl. Your help is really appreciated.

@Toby np, np. Hope it works on your PC as well :))

@IvanPetrov I have your sample code working. But when I try and modify your client code, so that rather taking a user supplied string in that while() loop it just tries to send/receive a basic message exchange - its breaking. On the server im getting a null reference exception when the server tries to read the message from the client and reply.

@Toby please consider upvoting/accepting my answer as it did answer your original question and feel free to post another question as this discussion seems to get very out of scope.

After faffing around with it for a bit, i have it working now I think. Super thankyou for your help!
